# NetworkManager service interfering with my connection in kali

Tags: networking, kali-linux, network-interface, networkmanager

I recently bought a new laptop for pentesting purposes, to mess around with stuff on my home network, and my intentions were to install virtualbox (oracle) and download a kali image to do stuff with. Here's some specs:

Host OS: windows 10

Host machine: Thinkpad t420

Virtual machine interface: Virtualbox

Wireless card: Alfa awus036h

Kali version: Latest possible

So basically, my virtual machine is working alright -nothing is directly wrong with it. I was messing around with my network card (alfa) which is connected via USB passthrough. And when networkmanager service is stopped, I am able to scan for networks. When it's on, I get no results.

When running `iw wlan0 scan` while networkmanager service is **stopped**:
[image: Snap]

As you can see, there are multiple networks that are visible to my card.

Now this is what happens when I scan again, but this time with networkmanager started:
[image: snip]

**no results**

This is very frustrating, so If you have any insight as to what could be the problem, please let me know.

**PS** What is the difference between the service `network-manager` and `NetworkManager`?

Thanks!

EDIT: The purpose is to connect to a wifi network. I used `iw wlan0 scan` as an example. When the service is active, my computer doesn't see any networks to connect to, therefor "disabling" the wifi on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you either have a AP/IP connectivity on an wifi interface, or you have it scanning/in monitor mode.

A wifi device cannot do both actions *at the same time*.

If you need Internet connectivity while in monitor mode, either you need another wifi stick, or use the default wifi of the machine, or using the ethernet interface.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not exactly sure what you mean, My card was not in monitor mode. I simple want to use the card as a normal card, and connect to a network to get wifi.

Comment: Me too.  It appears there are a lot of issues with Alfa and Kali when running through VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

When NetworkManager is running, it's already scanning for networks periodically, and its scans can interrupt your manual scan. That's why you don't get results when NetworkManager is running.

That's actually one of the problems NetworkManager is supposed to solve: there should be one central point of coordination for interrogating and configuring network settings, so that applications and commands don't step on each others' toes.

When NetworkManager is running, you should ask it for WiFi scan results instead of sending conflicting commands to the WiFi adapter: `nmcli dev wifi list` should give you the current list of SSIDs, and basic information on them.

If you need the deep technical details available only in the `iw <interface> scan` output, just use `iw <interface> scan dump` to get the existing results of the most recent scan: that works even with NetworkManager running. If you use `iw <interface> scan`, that will explicitly request the WiFi adapter to stop what it's doing and run a rescan *right now*, and that's what causes a conflict with NetworkManager.

If you must trigger a rescan at some particular time and NetworkManager is running, you can use `nmcli dev wifi rescan` for that.